# How do a cancel a click event using jQuery based on the results of a function in an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, preventdefault

My goal is to capture all the click events on in my website, check that the user is still logged in, then let them proceed or cancel their requested action based on the results of the ajax call which determines their current login status.

I'm going this due to users often having windows open with multiple selections made and reports run and internal tabs open... allowing the timeout's default behavior causes users to lose their work.

So, step 1: (intercept all click events)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).click(function(event) { fncCheckLogin(event); }); 
 });
```

Step 2: (Cancel the event for all clickable objects as a test)

```
 function fncCheckLogin(objEvent) { objEvent.preventDefault(); }
```

Step 3: (Check for Login Status)

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: "myURL",
 data: "{}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType:"json",
 complete: function(x){
   if(x){
     if (!isOpen) {
      DoSomeStuff
     }
   );
   isOpen = true;
   testMe(objEvent);
   }
   } else {
     if (isOpen) {
       isOpen = false;
     }
   }
 }
   });
```

Step 4: (prevent the action if the login has expired)

```
function testMe(objEvent) { if (isOpen) { objEvent.preventDefault(); }}
```

The "**isOpen**" variable is just identifying whether or not the logged-out-user script has run.  I was trying to access the preventDefault directly from the ajax call, but I moved it for testing stuff.

I think my problem is timing... if I put an alert in Step 4 prior to the if statement, the preventDefault command works, but otherwise it does not.  It is as though the event is completing prior to my ajax call, but I'm not positive that's the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: A) Please look into how to format your code B) In editing your post in an effort to fix the formatting, I came across a syntax error in your ajax complete method. `{DoSomeStuff})` where is that closing `)` comnig from?

Comment: made the edit as well, but I kept the syntax errors.

Comment: is all of the code after the `complete:` variable supposed to be part of the `complete` event handler?  If so, looks like testMe is outside of that, and it will execute right after the async call is made.  Move testMe inside your complete handler.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX stands for **asynchronous** Javascript and XML. The AJAX calls don't block by default, they run in the background while the rest of your code moves on. So you're correct that your event is completing prior to the completion of your AJAX call.

jQuery's ajax() method lets you specify async: false as one of the parameters to change this behavior, which should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this working is with async:false.

But, be aware that with async:false the "ajax" call will hang the browser until it returns.

Answer (score 0):

use [jquery event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). along with `async:false`. But as kingjiv advised, async:false has its shortcomings, use necessary UI paradigms (cursor to hourglass or ajax loading light box etc)

```
$("body").delegate("a", "click", function() { 

var loggedIn = false; //def treat as not Logged in

$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url: "myURL",
         data: "{}",
         async:false, 
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType:"json",
         complete: function(x){
           if(x) loggedIn = true;
         }
     });

if(loggedIn){
    //Call DOSOMETHING here
}

//return local var ajaxRet so the event will only bubble when loggedIn == true
return loggedIn; });
```